# scripts ecrypted with SHC work just by root

Tags: linux, fedora-23

I have encrypted a shell script namely test and it created test.x and test.x.c but but test.x is executed just by root! please help me.
I use linux fedora 22

```
~$ ls -l gg*     # gg is the name of shell script
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 yazdmet yazdmet 41    Jun 8 19:03 gg 
-rwx-wx--x. 1 yazdmet yazdmet 11248 Jun 8 19:08 gg.x 
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yazdmet yazdmet 9538  Jun 8 19:08 gg.x.c
```

Comment: could you edit your question with the output of `ls -l text.x text.x.c`

Comment: dear patrick test.x and test.x.c are example names. I dont have these now

Comment: so how can you claim that `test.x is executed just by root`?

Comment: and ofcours I work on my computer in my office I will contain ls -l tomorrow

Comment: yes you are right patrick I knew what you meant right now. I have fedora 20 on my lap top and dont have this problem but on my office PC I have fedora 22 and cant access it now

Comment: dear patrick I tested this in a fedora22 on another laptop and had the same problem when used shc -f test but when I use shc -T -f test, the test.x can be executed by a user! what do you think about this? shal this work on my PC in my office too?

Comment: this is ls -l gg* result (gg is the name of shell script)                      -rwxr-xr-x. 1 yazdmet yazdmet    41 Jun  8 19:03 gg
-rwx-wx--x. 1 yazdmet yazdmet 11248 Jun  8 19:08 gg.x
-rw-rw-r--. 1 yazdmet yazdmet  9538 Jun  8 19:08 gg.x.c

Comment: what is the content of `gg.x`? *(edit your question)*

Comment: dear patrick my problem solved thanks for your attention. problem solved by shc -T -f gg instead of shc -f gg :)

Comment: 1) your question didn't mention the **relevant** encryption procedure, that prevented any other people of helping you in time; next time, be sure to provide all the relevant details :) 2) I invite you to post an answer to your own question with all the relevant details of your solution.

Comment: A) I could not reproduce your problem B) the option `-T` does not appear in my version of the tool: which version/OS are you using?

Comment: sorry for late answer, I use fedora 22

Comment: Please fix your title spelling: when you write _ecrypted_, do you mean "decrypted" or "encrypted"?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** The encrypted file `script_name.x` that is generated by the following command

```
~$ shc -f script_name
```

can be executed only by **root**.

---

**Solution:** to execute the file with **any user** add the option `-T`:

```
 ~$ shc -T -f script_name
```